# ObservableCollection in ViewModel, List in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling to find a solution to the problem of having to maintain two lists.

I'm using `MVVM`, but don't want my model to use `ObservableCollection`.  I feel this is best to encapsulate and allows me to use different views/patterns (a console for example).  Instead of setting up my structure like this:

```
public class MainWindow {
  // handled in XAML file, no code in the .cs file
}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  // handles typical functions of a viewmodel base class
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBaseClass {
  public ObservableCollection<Account> accounts { get; private set; }
}

public class Administrator {
  public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }

  public void AddAccount(string username, string password) {
    // blah blah
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid having two different collections/lists in the case above.  I want only the model to handle the data, and the `ViewModel` to responsible for the logic of how its rendered.

Comment: it sounds like you'll need to have events on your Administrator class for delete/add/edit and have your MainWindowViewModel observe those changes.

Comment: Right and that's how it's implemented, but not I need to be able to bind to the list in Administrator and have it update when things are added, removed, or edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you could do is to use a ICollectionView in your Viewmodel to show your Model Data.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBaseClass {
 public ICollectionView accounts { get; private set; }
 private Administrator _admin;

  //ctor
  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
     _admin = new Administrator();
     this.accounts  = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this._admin.accounts);
  }

  //subscribe to your model changes and call Refresh
  this.accounts.Refresh();
```

xaml

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding accounts}" />
```

Comment: +1 for use of CollectionViewSource. Do note that the common naming standard uses [PascalCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for properties.